# В публицистике можно писать со строчной: государственный департамент США?

Tags: прописная

Мильчин:
3.10.16. Названия государственных учреждений несоциалистических стран в текстах официальных документов пишут с прописной буквы первое слово. Например: Государственный департамент США, Министерство обороны Франции.

Означает ли это, что и сейчас в публицистике можно писать со строчной: государственный департамент США?

Answer (score 1):

Нет уж. Если название учреждения приводится полностью, всё делаем по Мильчину.